# Move files to directory instead of recycle bin

Tags: windows-explorer, recycle-bin

I want all deleted files (with DEL-key or context menu > delete) not to be moved to the Recycle Bin but to another directory (like "Deleted Files" for instance), thus changing the default behavior of Windows Explorer.

Is this at all possible? Maybe by editing a registry key or putting a little script somewhere?

*Background:*

Files in redirected folders (per GPO) are not moved to the recycle bin but deleted instantly. With the required behavior I could simulate my own recycle bin.

Comment: I asked a question about how to create a batch script to move files from the Recycle Bin to another folder. Here is the [link](http://superuser.com/q/715673/219773).

Comment: And what about deleting permanentally?  Would you like to move those files to your folder too?

Comment: I want to "simulate" a recycle bin, so: no.

Answer (score 3):

I'd think it's unlikely Microsoft would permit this level of manipulation with the GUI/file management system--seems like it would be a gaping security hole.

It's not nearly as seamless as what you're looking for, but the next-best thing I can think of is to add a shortcut to your 'Deleted Files' folder to the Windows 'Send To' folder, per the instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/):

> You’ve seen the SendTo folder in action any time you right-click a file and select the Send To folder from the context menu. What you might be unaware of is that you can customize the items in this menu.
>
> ...
>
> To get to the SendTo folder, you’ll need to open up an Explorer window, and then paste in the following to the address bar:
>
> > %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
>
> ...
>
> Let’s say you wanted to add an item to the Send To menu to open files in Notepad. You could just drag a shortcut to Notepad into this folder, or create a new shortcut.

For your purposes, create a shortcut to the 'Deleted Files' folder in this ...\SendTo folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all clear about what you're trying to accomplish with this. The Recycle Bin is just a folder on the hard drive (actually named "$Recycle.Bin" -- and, of course, hidden from normal views.)  But if you want to rename it to "Deleted Files" you can do so in the registry, by editing the default Reg_SZ value at HKCU|SOFTWARE|MICROSOFT|WINDOWS|CURRENT VERSION|EXPLORER|CLSID|{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}

There are detailed step-by-step instructions for renaming it here:
http://www.wikihow.com/Rename-the-Windows-Recycle-Bin

If that won't suffice, please clarify what you are trying to accomplish with this.